# CodeIgniter displaying multi select instead of dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm pulling data from a database to populate a drop down list. I am working on function that updates data in a table. When the user clicks update it brings them to a form with the data from the row populated so they can update the necessary information. The drop down box should have the value that is in the table selected. However when I load the page it displays a multi-select option box and all the options are selected.

**Model**

```
public function edit_recrew()
{
    $this->load->model('atisroad_model');
    $this->data['record'] = $this->atisroad_model->edit_recrew();
    $this->data['train_status'] = $this->atisroad_model->trainstatusli();
    $this->data['train_direction'] = $this->atisroad_model->traindirli();
    $this->load->view('atis/edit_recrew', $this->data);
}
```

**View**

```
        <tr>
        <td>Train Direction:</td>
        <td><?=form_dropdown('train_direction', $train_direction, set_value('train_direction', $train_direction));?>
</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>Train Status:</td>
        <td> <?=form_dropdown('train_status', $train_status, set_value('train_status', $train_status));?>
    </tr>
```

**Controller**

```
public function edit_recrew()
{
    $this->db->where('train_id', $this->uri->segment(3));
    $query = $this->db->get('trains_road');
    return $query->result();
}
public function trainstatusli()
{
    $result = $this->db->get('train_status');
    $return = array();
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($result->result_array() as $row) {
            $return[$row['status']] = $row['status'];
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
public function traindirli()
{
    $result = $this->db->get('train_direction');
    $return = array();
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($result->result_array() as $row) {
            $return[$row['direction']] = $row['direction'];
        }
    }
    return $return;
```

Answer (score 0):

*I'm assuming that you are using Codeigniter 3 (although I'm pretty sure that this is valid even for the 2.x).*

You cannot use set_value like that: you are passing an array as a default to set_value which will return that array as selected values for the form_dropdown function but, and here's your problem, if you pass an array as third parameter to form_dropdown it will render a multiselect.
Here the official refence [form_dropdown](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=dropdown#form_dropdown)
and [set_value](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=set_value#set_valuehttp://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=set_value#set_value)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the values in the third parameter, and it worked.

```
<tr>
   <td>Train Direction:</td>
   <td><?=form_dropdown('train_direction', $train_direction, $value->train_direction));?>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Train Status:</td>
   <td> <?=form_dropdown('train_status', $train_status, $value->train_status);?>
</tr>
```